# what is the default file template in drupal when you set your own theme?

Tags: theming

What is the default template in drupal when you set your own template and you don't have page.tpl.php
??
where does the html beeing rendered from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the active theme doesn't have a page.tpl.php, the [default page.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7) from core is used.

See [Default theme implementations](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/group/themeable/7) for more information.

Comment: and the default regions?

Comment: Regions are defined in the theme's .info file, they all have them. There aren't 'default regions' as such

Comment: yes but i haven' defined my regions and even such so, it displays
header
footer
content
etc..
in Admin ->Blocks

Comment: @Clive the default region in .info D7 can be found https://www.drupal.org/node/171206#default-regions. and for more information about the defualt template check modules/system (core Drupal module) for the templates structure